# Javascript image rotator slow in older browsers

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, rotator

I've created a simple image rotator with javascript, but it's slow with "older browsers" (for example IE 6 , 7 and 8). Images will load first I think, then start the rotator.. Some tips to make it faster?

Why I created a rotator by myself? All the rotators I've found cut (cropped) the images. I need the  full image... with when necessary some white space left/right or top/bottom.

Javascript part:

```
//Loop through pictures
var tid = setInterval(mycode, 3000);
function mycode() {

    if($.random(0,1) == 1){
        //Fade
        $('#alleplaatjes img.active').fadeOut(500,function(){
            $(this).removeClass();

            if($(this).next().length == 0){
                $('#alleplaatjes img').first().fadeIn(500);
                $('#alleplaatjes img').first().addClass('active');
            } else {
                $(this).next().fadeIn(500);
                $(this).next().addClass('active');
            }
        });
    } else {
        //Slide
        $('#alleplaatjes img.active').slideUp(500,function(){
            $(this).removeClass();

            if($(this).next().length == 0){
                $('#alleplaatjes img').first().slideDown(500);
                $('#alleplaatjes img').first().addClass('active');
            } else {
                $(this).next().slideDown(500);
                $(this).next().addClass('active');
            }
        });
    }
};
```

PHP part:

```
<?php

$dir = "/home/zwuq/domains/***/public_html/afbeelding/";
foreach(glob($dir."*") as $file){
    $afbeelding = 'afbeelding/'.str_replace($dir, '', $file);
    $toevoeging = FALSE;
    if(!$eerste_plaatje){
        $toevoeging = ' class="active"';
        $eerste_plaatje = $afbeelding;
    }
    $plaatjes .= '<img'.$toevoeging.' src="'.$afbeelding.'" style="max-width: 99%; max-height: 99%;">';
}

?>
```

HTML part:

```
<div id="alleplaatjes" style="width:100%; height:100%; margin:0px; padding:0px; z-index:1; text-align: center;">
    <? echo $plaatjes; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Define "older browsers"?

Comment: Do you just mean older browsers, or do you mean older computers with older browsers?

Comment: Just added :) For example IE6, 7 and 8

Comment: I can code image rotation that is freaking slow in newer browsers as well. That's no big deal. You probably expect a bit too much from a web-browser. Code for use, not slick effects. You can add them if you detect it's a fast browser, so everybody can just use your site.

Comment: `cut the images` does that mean cropped? or are you referring to how some perform transitions?

Comment: I mean cropped. Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: You think your images will load first ? Dude sorry but I can't believe that you made this on your own, if you should now what gets loaded when...

Comment: ps: try to avoid dutch in code, always use english ;)

Comment: @Topener: Since most Dutch people speak English better than many Americans :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One suggestion is not to use `setInterval`. If the operation takes too long (in your case, longer than 3 seconds), the accumulated delay will cause your animation to get even worse.

To try my suggestion just call `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval`, then at the end of your `mycode`, you call setTimeout again. Ideally, you keep track of how late your function was called and adjust the interval passed to the next timeout.

For best results here at StackOverflow, posting an example on http://jsfiddle.net will let other people see the problem live and may help us help you.

**Another suggestion**

Cache your jQuery objects. For example instead of:

```
    $(this).removeClass();
    if($(this).next().length == 0){
        $('#alleplaatjes img').first().fadeIn(500);
        $('#alleplaatjes img').first().addClass('active');
    } else {
        $(this).next().fadeIn(500);
        $(this).next().addClass('active');
    }
```

You should have

```
    // prepending jquery variables with $ to distinguish them
    var $this = $(this),
        $next = $this.next();
    $this.removeClass();

    if( $next.length == 0 ){
        var $first = $('#alleplaatjes img').first();
        $first.fadeIn(500);
        $first.addClass('active');
    } else {
        $next.fadeIn(500);
        $next.addClass('active');
    }
```